# What is the intersection of a countable set of intervals $(n, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

If I have a countable set of intervals $\{ A_n \}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ where $A_n = (n, \infty)$, and take the intersection $ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n $ my assumption is that this set would be $\varnothing$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n$ would be $(\infty,\infty)$. Or in the case of the extended reals where $A_n = [n, \infty]$, then the same limit would be $[\infty,\infty]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t toss limits around quite that cavalierly: if you applied the same reasoning to sets $B_n=\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$, you’d conclude that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}B_n=(0,0)=\varnothing$, which is false: $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}B_n=\{0\}$.

However, your conclusion is correct: $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n=\varnothing$. The reason is that if $x$ is any real number, then by the Archimedean property there is an $n_x\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $n_x\ge x$. Then $x\notin A_{n_x}$, and therefore $x\notin\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n$. Since this is true of every $x\in\Bbb R$, it must be that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n=\varnothing$.

Comment: For your first point, I think that a singleton in $\mathbb{R}$ can only be a closed set.

Comment: @user1876508: That’s perfectly true, but it’s also irrelevant: every closed set in $\Bbb R$ is an intersection of countably many open sets.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection is $\emptyset$ since no real number is larger than $n$ for all integers $n$. (I'm not sure what you mean by the limit of the intervals though.)

Comment: $A_1$ would be $(1,\infty)$, $A_7$ would be $(7,\infty)$, etc.